# How do I get this Ruby on Rails+Devise+Stripe sign up form to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Logs:

```
    Started POST "/users" for 173.66.113.33 at 2016-11-20 23:49:12 +0000
Cannot render console from 173.66.113.33! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sia/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3)
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"N3QCRhKLthRAb3pKewlRcnGpWIMP991jebtxBAGuba1fwYLqpSDGmDxidbqYD2aMxfvwfYmjJ7mowBL1PydSCA==", "plan"=>"1", "user"=>{"email"=>"asdasfafa@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "asdasfafa@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/registrations/_basic.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 253ms (Views: 63.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

[image: Sign Up form screenshot]

The entire codebase is at [project@github](https://github.com/Faisal-Hassan/sia)

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: I think we need more information than this, it looks like the plan you set (id of 1) in this request isn't a valid plan?

Comment: What other info should I add? I added the project link on github, by the way.